# Windows application to apply photo filters like mobile apps?

Tags: photos

Today we have lots of mobile application to apply cool filters to our photography with just one ..touch. 
It is cool and comfortable, but i would like to use some easy-to.use windows application to do the same.. with a click! I don't need lots of stuff like photoshop, but simply a software with hundreds of filters (vintage, bw etc) to apply to my photo!
Is there some windows application ? 
And what about Linux ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about a one-click solution, but have a look at XNretro (http://www.xnview.com/en/xnretro/). It can add instagram-like effects to your photographs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to spend some money [Adobe Photoshop Lightroom](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/photoshop-lightroom.html) has a presets function which allows for one-click effects to be applied to your images.

There are many pre-built packages of these presets available, for example [Trey Ratcliff's Lightroom Presets](http://www.stuckincustoms.com/lightroom-presets/).

For a free option, there are 36 filters available in Google's [Picasa](http://picasa.google.co.uk/).